# How to solve the error comes while scrolling listview slowly in Xamarin.Forms Android with DataTemplateSelector?

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, targetinvocationexception

I've created a Xamarin.forms project and I've created DataTemplateSelector which is working fine in iOS but in Andoird, when I scroll faster app don't crash but when I scroll slower the app crashes and TargetInvocationException comes. I'm not even able to track the error and its the choice of error when it wants to come, sometimes it don't crash with same data either scroll faster or slower and sometimes it immediately crashes with the same data when we try to scroll a little bit.

I've logged the error and below is the error in log:

```
Time: 12/14/2016 1:37:48 PM
Error: Unhandled Exception
System.Exception: CurrentDomainOnUnhandledException ---> Java.Lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException ---> Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException: Exception of type 'Java.Lang.Reflect.InvocationTargetException' was thrown. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException (System.ExceptionArgument argument, System.ExceptionResource resource) [0x00011] in <368820a9888f43ddb85d18e87189adbf>:0 
  at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException () [0x00000] in <368820a9888f43ddb85d18e87189adbf>:0 
  at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].get_Item (System.Int32 index) [0x0000c] in <368820a9888f43ddb85d18e87189adbf>:0 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in <368820a9888f43ddb85d18e87189adbf>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00056] in <368820a9888f43ddb85d18e87189adbf>:0 
  at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <368820a9888f43ddb85d18e87189adbf>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.BindingExpression+BindingExpressionPart.TryGetValue (System.Object source, System.Object& value) [0x00026] in <7b0368eb3d0f405da776a09e3171532a>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <368820a9888f43ddb85d18e87189adbf>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallNonvirtualBooleanMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x000a8] in <a043032cf94a485190047a14918b9f60>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.InvokeVirtualBooleanMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.IJavaPeerable self, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00068] in <a043032cf94a485190047a14918b9f60>:0 
  at Android.Views.View.DispatchTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent e) [0x00036] in <206240d88f7f44d795aacbc1d5348a1f>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlatformRenderer.DispatchTouchEvent (Android.Views.MotionEvent e) [0x00035] in <d572ae0ccf89437fad1de1370c623a06>:0 
  at Android.Views.View.n_DispatchTouchEvent_Landroid_view_MotionEvent_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_e) [0x00011] in <206240d88f7f44d795aacbc1d5348a1f>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:035bfbdb-dd96-451c-b894-4f2fd770769d (intptr,intptr,intptr)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Below is the code of xaml.cs file

> http://pastebin.com/UvyxMwtP

Below is the code of xaml file

> http://pastebin.com/VVfKAjnn

Below is the code of DataTemplateSelector

> http://pastebin.com/nn2dGZAW

Below are the code of templates:

> http://pastebin.com/0mJD1gJ1
>   http://pastebin.com/uJiLnBKK
>   http://pastebin.com/gcj2TuJ1
>   http://pastebin.com/c8TByW1z
>   http://pastebin.com/ww51B4Su

Comment: From your error info I suppose that your listView loads a lot of data that causes the memory to overflow.Can you show more detail about your listView adapter.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT yeah you are right. But I tried with less data with just two posts and the app crashed. Now what I did is, I just removed the RecycleElement option and now the error is coming one in twenty times. May be the memory requirement for the recycling elements is much more.